# How do I put elements two or three in a row?

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning, fluid

I have to build a fluid, scalable, device-independent layout where I need to put 4 elements in a row so that they resize and stick together. Let’s say, 4 images, as they naturally are - one above  another, and I just want to group them in two rows - 2 images side by side in 1 row so that I have no problems with layout or structure. Can you show me how? Thank you!

Comment: Look into flexbox in combination with media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox and make it responsive like this:

```css
.element-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.element-row {
  display: flex;
}

.element {
  flex: 0 1 46%;
  margin: 0 2% 20px 2%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.element img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-container">
  <div class="element-row">
    <div class="element">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element-row">
    <div class="element">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. the structure works, but after the elements meet each other during the screen width test, the elements will not resize - they won't become smaller automatically, and I have no idea how to make them resizable...